# Get total number of inserted rows count in batch insertion Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = session.prepare("INSERT INTO table_name( column1) VALUES(?)");
BatchStatement batch = new BatchStatement();
batch.add(preparedStatement.bind(value1));
batch.add(preparedStatement.bind(value2));
session.execute(batch);
```

Now I want to know how many rows have been inserted in the database.

```
batch.size();
```

will return only the batch size, not the inserted record count.

Comment: It's not recommended to use batches when inserts will be performend for different partitions.

Comment: Yes, you are right @Alex Ott, but the problem is I want to know how many numbers of records have been inserted. Do you have answer for that?

Comment: By default `BatchStatement` is logged, so if it fails, then it should be retried, or you'll get exception

Comment: In my case, I have a unique key constraint, let's say (some_id, created_date) now if I try to add using below batch (1,12345) (2, 12345) where (1, 12345) it is already stored only (2,12345) wil be added, So I want to know how many rows inserted.

So currently it is adding only nonduplicate entries of any batch, So I want to know which are the unique entries of my batch.

Comment: The inserts in Cassandra are upserts, until you're using `IF NOT EXISTS`

Comment: I simply want to know from 10 rows of batch how many rows were inserted. Because some of the rows already inserted and I want to maintain the insert_counter.

Answer (score 0):

Batches are logged by default in Cassandra which guarantees atomocity if successful. So the size you get with the client will be the same size as what's inserted in Cassandra **if the request is successful** (otherwise it's 0).

More info here: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlBatch.html#cqlBatch__cql-log-unlog

Comment: In my case, I have a unique key constraint, let's say 
(some_id, created_date) now if I try to add using below batch
(1,12345)
(2, 12345) 

where (1, 12345) it is already stored only (2,12345) wil be added, So I want to know how many rows inserted.